# Wordpress Shortcodes not rendering content (2 themes)

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been having this problem for several weeks now, and would really like to get it resolved. I'm seeing issues like this all over the internet, however everyone is coming up empty.

I have 2 custom wordpress themes. One on a Linux (cPanel) Server, and one on a Windows (IIS) Server. Both of them have different custom themes, both of them are loaded with content. The two server php.ini's are identical (or as close as they can be). When I use the provided wordpress theme shortcodes are working fine. However when I take either of the custom themes, and make them active, shortcodes cease to work, they will show up on sidebars, and posts, but there is NO content, and by no content I mean: It shows the title of the widget, but not the actual widget itself.

I am quite literally at my wits-end here. This will be the 4th forum post in over a month on different sites, trying to get an answer. No one can help me anywhere. I'm hoping since I've had luck here with other issues, that maybe someone has seen this happen. Even custom shortcodes are not rendering.

I thought maybe it was because a script isn't called in the custom theme, but comparing the Wordpress TwentyTwelve theme and mine there are not any differences in the header file.

I've called  wp_head(); and wp_meta();....So confused. Please help!!!

**functions.php**

```
<?php
function wpb_widgets_init() {

register_sidebar( array(
'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'wpb' ),
'id' => 'sidebar-1',
'description' => __( 'The main sidebar appears on the right on each page except the front page template', 'wpb' ),
'before_widget' => '',
'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
'before_title' => '<div class="padding"><div class="top">',
'after_title' => '</div><div class="bottom">'));
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_widgets_init' );
apply_filters('the_content',get_the_content( $more_link_text, $stripteaser, $more_file ))
?>
```

**sidebar.php**

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without code this is difficult to answer, but a good shot might be the use of `get_the_content()` instead of `the_content()` within your loop. Using `get_the_content()` will not apply the `the_content` filters. See:

> If you use plugins that filter content (add_filter('the_content')), then this will not apply >the filters, unless you call it this way (using apply_filters):

```
    <?php apply_filters('the_content',get_the_content( $more_link_text, $stripteaser, $more_file )) ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content

Comment: This is outside of the loop. I will attach my functions.php and the widget area code to the post above.

Comment: Why is there the apply_filters call in your functions.php?

`apply_filters('the_content',get_the_content( $more_link_text, $stripteaser, $more_file ))`

If this is outside the loop, Wordpress doesn't know what content to grab? You may use WP_Query to generate a new loop, or are you missing some code here?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but i think you misunderstand. I am trying to display the shortcode on the sidebar, or footer. Not under or around post content. For example, I am trying to use a calendar widget, when i drag the widget to the sidebar, it will show the div it's supposed to be contained in, but not the actual calendar itself.

Comment: Aha, I think you are using the term 'shortcode' incorrect then. Shortcodes are only used within post content. If you would like to use it outside the loop you may use the following code:

        apply_filters('the_content', '[my-custom-shortcode]');

Is that what you meant to do or are you simply stating that no widgets (default Wordpress or custom) are showing up at all (except for the before-widget and after-widget HTML)? Widgets usually do not use shortcodes.

Comment: No I'm stating that they work fine on the default theme, but will not work at all on any custom theme. I'm following the same path I always do (been developing wordpress sites for years), but still no go. You are correct in saying that all that's being displayed is the before and after html. Nothing else displays.

** Edit: I've used many widgets that utilize shortcodes. I've never heard anywhere that they are uncommon.

Comment: It's been a week since anyone has responded, am I to assume this can not be solved?